# Angular http.get doesn't work with local json file

Tags: json, angular, http-get

I have a demo angular app that has an `api/products/products.json` file for use with `http.get()`. But when I made my own component and services to hit my own custom local json, it gives 404 error in Chrome console. It doesn't work even if the json file is in the same directory as the service, and consumed with `http.get(numbers.json)`, it only works if I put it under the `api` folder like `api/numbers.json`. Does Angular have a rule where local json for http consume must exist under `api` folder?

edit: found that putting the file under assets folder works, but if I create a custom folder, it doesn't work.

Comment: it looks like the file is not packed with webpack. I would need your webpack.config.js file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the CLI, then you need to add the folder here:

```
  "assets": [
    "assets",
    "api",
    "favicon.ico"
  ],
```

This is part of the `angular-cli.json` file.

Comment: great, that worked, but why do I need to restart `ng-serve` for this to take effect?

Comment: My guess is that since this is part of the configuration file, that it is read in only on start. So you have to restart with ng serve.

Comment: Sadly, did not work for me! https://stackoverflow.com/q/47768897/5346095

Answer (score 0):

if you are using angular-cli 
add you json file inside the assets folder
and add this to get
`this.http.get('./assets/products.json');`

it will be seen by this way