# Angular : Unable to GET local json using HttpClient

Tags: angular, http, typescript, angular5

I am using the latest `HttpClient` component provided in `Angular5` to make a get request for local json but I am getting 404 ever since. I have already imported `HttpClientModule` module in my `app.module.ts`.

Snapshot of folder structure:

[image]

I am making the call from blog-detail component for `blog-list.json`. Here is my code:

```
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1').subscribe((data:Blog[]) => {
    this.http.get('app/api/blog-list.json').subscribe((data:Blog[]) => {
         this.blogs = data;
    });
  }
```

I get following error:

```
GET http://localhost:909/app/api/blog-list.json 404 (Not Found)
```

Even if I try to open the file in browser directly by hitting http://localhost:909/src/app/api/blog-list.json I get the application served there instead of the json file.

Please note that the commented request to a rest api on web is successful but fails for call only to a local json file.

Comment: make sure you are trying to access jwon from local web server not from file system. web client is to make http calls to web server is required

Comment: @AniruddhaDas I am running app in dev mode? Am I doing it in incorrect way?

Comment: Make sure: (1) your file is present on the server at appropriate location, (2) your server process has access to the disk/file (in some cases this is true), (3) you have apt MIME media type for JSON "application/json".

Comment: @Fenton Tried but go same error: http://localhost:909/app/api/blog-list.json 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @Abhi I am running this is dev mode.

Comment: Sadly that did not work as well! :( http://localhost:909/src/app/api/blog-list.json 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @Fenton Its vishalgulati.com/src/app

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to fix this but its kinda weird that why it happened at the first place.

For this I had to update the .angular-cli.json and add the path to api folder in assets property. Now the assets property looks like:

```
"assets": [
    "assets",
    "app/api",
    "favicon.ico"
 ]
```

Comment: I would add that I only had to use "api" and not "app/api" and most importantly I had to STOP the server and restart it again with ng serve -o